# Search Plugin for Safari

Tags: search, safari

How do we create a search plugin for Safari? Like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830/firefox-users-here-is-your-stackoverflow-search-plugin)

Comment: dont see where this is related to SO, belongs on Meta-SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a search plugin specifically for this site, someone will have to write one.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://pimpmysafari.com/plugins/keywurl) is a Safari plugin whereby you can customize it to search other sites. May work with Stack Overflow (I haven't tried it). Check out that site too for other Safari plugins.

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote Safari Omnibar which is a native extension for Safari that let's you add custom search keywords for searching directly on particular sites. You can also set the default search engine to any other site.

[Safari Omnikey Homepage](http://marioestrada.github.com/safari-omnikey/)

[Source Code](https://github.com/marioestrada/safari-omnikey)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Safari doesn't have a Search plugin capability.  You could try [Inquisitor](http://www.inquisitorx.com/safari/index_en.php); just add the URL https://stackoverflow.com/search?s=%@